# Is it possible to prevent Google Meet participants from seeing all other participants?

Tags: google-chrome, google-meet

I conduct a live private one-way lecture with Google Meet (I am the host) and participants only need to hear, watch and submit their work after the lecture. For some privacy reason,  I want to prevent all participants from being identified by other participants. They can see me and I can see them (for tracking attendance).

Is it possible in Google Meet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to hide invitees from each others, you need to make sure to enable the feature "Hide invitee from each other" on the settings panel when creating an event:

[image]

Comment: Sorry. Is this feature available for free version? I cannot see such options available. :-)

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy: It's possible - I don't have this version.